# Setting one autonumber that will sync to all (related) objects

Tags: custom-object, formula-field, field-update, auto-number, sequential

We have decided we want all Leads, Opportunities, Quotes and a few custom objects to inherit the same autonumber so that it is easy to see related objects just by the number.

Leads should get an LD-Number (LD-0001), then when it is converted to an Opportunity, that inherits the LD-Number and it becomes an OP-Number with the same numerals (OP-0001). If a new opportunity is created without a related lead, it must take the next sequential autonumber as its OP-Number (OP-0002). Then the next new object (either Lead or Opportunity) would be ##-0003 and so on...

```
LD-0001  OP-0001  QU-0001  YY-0001
LD-0002  XX-XXXX  XX-XXXX  XX-XXXX
LD-0003  OP-0003  QU-0003  YY-0003
XX-XXXX  OP-0004  XX-XXXX  XX-XXXX
LD-0005  OP-0005  XX-XXXX  XX-XXXX etc...
```

Any lead converted must take the number with it to the opportunity. Likewise a Quote on Opportunity OP-0002 would be QU-0002, but as there may be multiple quotes on an object, it would have to be QU-0002-01, then QU-0002-02 etc... Any quote on Opportunity OP-0003 would be QU-0003-01, QU-0003-02... I don't want to use incremental numbers across records

```
QU-0002-01
QU-0002-02
QU-0003-03
QU-0003-04
QU-0003-05
QU-0004-06...
```

I need it to reset to 01 for each Quote...

```
QU-0002-01
QU-0002-02
QU-0003-01
QU-0003-02
QU-0003-01
QU-0004-01
```

I was thinking of using a new custom object called "NumberStore" which starts at NS-0001 and will keep the autonumber record for all new objects needing a number. A new lead would take the number to it's LD-number (LD-0001) and increment the NumberStore by one. The next new lead would get the number LD-0002 and increment NumberStore by one but if a new Opportunity is created before the next new lead, it takes the NumberStore number (NS-0002) as its OP-number (OP-0002) and increments it by one and then there would never be a lead with LD-0002 as the next available number for the next new object record would be ##-0003 so on and so on...

A simple combination of formula fields to inherit the number and assign new letters for converted leads and a field update rule to increment the NumberStore number each time there is a new lead or new opportunity (but not if an opportunity is converted from a lead) should be fairly straight forward?

Hope it makes sense? Is this overcomplicating it? Is there a simpler way to synchronise all the object numbers that Salesforce already does or should I start implementing a solution myself? Using straight forward autonumber fields on each object does not link them. I can also see issues if a record is deleted it can affect the number sequence hence I though a centralised number record (NumberStore) that is incremented with Field Update rules on Process Builder or perhaps a Flow would be necessary.

Please can somebody offer better solutions or suggest why this may not be a good idea?

Comment: [1/2] Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). We had a requirement for very specific _Account_ numbering, to use SF as our Account Master with integrations into other systems - some legacy that could only handle certain number of characters, etc. There was some prefix requirements based on Region, etc. - similar to your 'LD', 'QU', etc. There was some number sequencing requirements. We implemented an _Account Number Sequence_ Custom Object with fields to hold the different parts as well as a field to hold the "final" account number....

Comment: [2/2] ....We have a 'Generate Account Number' button that kicks off quite complex Apex to find any existing numbers, generate the next number, save it in the Custom Object, and save it in the custom account number field on the _Account_. Not that we are all experts - most of us were fairly new to S;, but we could not come up with a better solution. It works! It is not _quite_ the same as your requirements, but similar enough.

Comment: OOTB Autonumber will not work as you point out; custom solutions need to be written to prevent concurrent transactions from grabbing the same nextNumber

Comment: Thanks @Moonpie, it looks like your solution is very similar. I wanted to try a no-code solution before looking at Apex (especially if it is complex!) but the custom object route for the numbering looks more and more sensible.
Thanks cropredy, I figured autonumber would be problematic. I will try and post later when I come up with my solution...
Many thanks for the replies all.

Comment: We had some very complex logic - Different Account Types had different numbering templates, and the Account "number" itself (which included text) included some regional abbreviations. So due alone to that complexity, we had to go Apex. Since the logic of your requirements is not that complex, it _might_ be possible in a Flow without calling Apex. Good luck!